# MeteorJS promise reject through future not working as expected

Tags: meteor, es6-promise

i have written a Meteor method that is correctly returning data but not correctly processing errors. the method itself uses a Future, and calls into a utility function that uses an ES6 promise.

i am calling the method from the browser console. the "happy path" works as expected, and i can console.log() out my results in the browser. the error path does not come back.

here is the method:

```
import {bar} from './bar';

const Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({
    'foo': function(num) {
        check(num, Number);

        let future = new Future();

        bar(num).then(function(result) {
            future.return(result);
        }, function(error) {
            future.throw(error);
        });

        return future.wait();
    }
});
```

here is the utility:

```
const bar = function(num) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if (num === 3) {
            let msg = 'nope';
            console.error(msg);
            reject(msg);
        }

        resolve('good');
    });
};

export {bar};
```

here is me calling it in the browser (Chrome on OSX):

```
Meteor.call('foo', 1, function(e,r) {console.log('e:', e);  console.log('r:', r);})
undefined
VM771:1 e: undefined
VM771:1 r: good
Meteor.call('foo', 1, function(e,r) {console.log('e:', e);  console.log('r:', r);})
undefined
VM773:1 e: undefined
VM773:1 r: good
Meteor.call('foo', 1, function(e,r) {console.log('e:', e);  console.log('r:', r);})
undefined
VM775:1 e: undefined
VM775:1 r: good
Meteor.call('foo', 3, function(e,r) {console.log('e:', e);  console.log('r:', r);})
undefined
```

notice i called it 3x on the happy path, and 1x with the unhappy path. the unhappy path never comes back.

if i call it with the happy path again, this happens:

```
Meteor.call('foo', 1, function(e,r) {console.log('e:', e);  console.log('r:', r);})
undefined
```

now it's "stuck" until some buffer somewhere is cleared out. i can clear it out by, say, reloading the browser.

if i keep hitting the unhappy path, i *will* see some "nope" messages in the server console, but eventually that gets stuck, too. so i'm unclear if it's a client or server issue (i suspect server).

does anyone know why:

1. i'm not seeing any return from that rejected promise path, and
2. why hitting that path breaks that method going forward?

i'm on Meteor v1.4.3.2

**update**:

i also tried the catch syntax, but behavior was the same:

```
    bar(num).then(result => {
        console.log('result:', result);
        future.return(result);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error:', error);
        future.throw(error);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried `throw` instead of `reject` on the future?

Comment: @MaxG. yes, with the same result. the issue is with the promise somehow, and not the future. since my example is synchronous, as a test i took out the promise and used throw for the error condition. it worked as expected.

Comment: fwiw, it all works ok if i don't use reject() in the promise, and just "throw new Meteor.Error" from the promise. feels dirty. i want the reject to work, so leaving this open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have upgraded to Meteor 1.4.4.2 and i am unable to reproduce this issue.

and fwiw, i also discovered that, unlike the $q library i've used in the past, calling reject() on an ES6 promise does *not* exit the function. it will happily keep running and, in my example above, also call resolve(). it's possible that that was confusing something in that previous version of Meteor.

so now i'm doing this to ensure i exit the function on any resolve() or reject():

```
const bar = function(num) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if (num === 3) {
            let msg = 'nope';
            console.error(msg);
            return reject(msg);
            //console.log('omg why am i here');
        }

        return resolve('good');
    });
};
```